# map<string,string> implementation in grpc for .netCore

Tags: dictionary, asp.net-core, .net-core, grpc

Using a map in the proto file of grpc for .net core to send a dictionary as a request parameter makes it private field(read-only) in the auto-generated code. So I am unable to assign the dictionary to map and pass it in the API request. How do I make it read-write.?

```
Sample proto request: 

service xyz{
rpc testTrans(TestRequest) returns (TestResponse);
}
message TestRequest {
  map<string,string> props = 1;
}
```

so the auto-generated code looks like this :

```
    public const int PropsFieldNumber = 1;

    private static readonly pbc::MapField<string, string>.Codec _map_Props_codec
        = new pbc::MapField<string, string>.Codec(pb::FieldCodec.ForString(10), pb::FieldCodec.ForString(18), 10);

    private readonly pbc::MapField<string, string> Props_ = new pbc::MapField<string, string>();

    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
    public pbc::MapField<string, string> Props {
      get { return Props_; }
    }
```

So now when i try to assign property in request as below, it throws error :
**Property or Indexer TestRequest.Props could not be assigned to -- it is read only.**

```
       public static void testTrans(Dictionary<string, string> test)
        {
             var res = client.InitTrans(new TestRequest
                {
                    Props = test
                });
        }
```

Comment: Please provide us Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, you can read how to write it here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DusanRadovanovic Please check now.

Comment: I don't know how to make it read-write, but you can solve your problem by adding test dictionary to CinemaProps dictionary

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is being prevented when you want to directly declare and initialize the value with:

```
var res = client.InitTrans(new TestRequest
            {
              //Property could not be assigned to -- it is read only...error
              Props = new Map<string,string>.Add("somekey", "somevalue");
              // Alternatively the same problem will also occur when you do
              // Props = new Map<string,string>.Add(SomeDict);
            }
```

Instead there should be work around by initializing your variable and then add the value(s) to the dictionary later (after the initialization of the entire message object).

```
     var res = new TestRequest{};

     //test is some dictionary

     res.TestRequest.Props.Add(test);

     //alternatively you can also add with (key, value)

     res.TestRequest.Props.Add("someKey", "someValue);
```